# Django TemplateDoesNotExist Error on Windows machine

Tags: python, django

I have been following the tutorial for Django **[Tango with Django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/setup.html#django-basics)**

I was trying to add a template as instructed on the [link](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/templates_static.html).
I am working with Python 2.7, Django 1.8 on a windows 7 machine.

Below is the error that I get:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /rango/
rango/index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:rango/index.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 46
```

---

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\rango\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\rango\index.html    (File does not exist)
```

Below is my file structure:

```
tango_with_django_project
+-- rango
|   +--views.py
|   +--other files
+-- tango_with_django_project
|   +--templates
|   |   +--rango
|   |   |  +--index.html
|   +--settings.py
|   +--other files
+-- db.sqlite3
+-- manage.py`
```

I have given the template path as below in **`settings.py`**:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)
```

And have set the view as in **`views.py`**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
   context_dict = {'boldmessage': "I am bold font from the context"}
   return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)
```

Without using the template, it works fine and displays plain text. But when I do the changes required for the template, it does not work and throws the Error.
There are many links on SO with the same issue but none have worked for me.
The [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150341/django-the-templatedoesnotexist-error) with almost the same Error description and on Windows machine has a vague answer.

I have tried directly specifying the **absolute path** instead of getting it from `os.path` and have also tried placing the template folder in different paths.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Django is not looking in your `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. Are you sure that you are not overriding that variable? In your view, try using `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS)`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini : Even I think `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is not being set with the value that I specify. It checks for the templates in these paths `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin;C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth`
I tried what you told me too and got the below error:
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting TEMPLATE_DIRS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Comment: the error you get is pretty self-explainatory. Have you set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or have you called `settings.configure()`? How is your web application running? (manage.py, a web server, ...)

Comment: It is running on the development server using commands `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me was removing the below piece of code from `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
     {
         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
         'DIRS': [],
         'APP_DIRS': True,
         'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And adding :

`TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('C:/Users/vaulstein/tango_with_django_project/templates',)`

**OR**

Changing the line 4th line below :

```
TEMPLATES = [
   {
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
       'DIRS': ['C:/Users/vaulstein/tango_with_django_project/templates'],
       'APP_DIRS': True,
       'OPTIONS': {
           'context_processors': [
               'django.template.context_processors.debug',
               'django.template.context_processors.request',
               'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
           ],
       },
   },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the application name to **INSTALLED_APPS** list in **settings.py**

find the following list in settings.py,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
]
```

add your application name to that list. In your case,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tango_with_django_project'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case modifying **INSTALLED_APPS** doesn't help, so based on previos answers I just modified my **settings.py** in the following way:

1. Add `import OS`
2. Add  `os.getcwd()` into `DIRS`

So it looks like this:

```
...
from pathlib import Path
import os
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.getcwd()],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```